# Is there a difference between .quit and .exit in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite, task, scheduler, exit

I am writing a VBScript script to execute an SQL query in the SQLite shell and was wondering if I needed to use .quit or .exit.

When I set up a task in the task scheduler to run this VBScript script, the SQLite shell doesn’t exit/quit properly due to which I get a new instance created every time the task scheduler run and this is causes the SQL query to not be executed. When I double click on the VBScript script it runs fine and SQLite shell exists gracefully.

How can I fix this?

The script:

```
Dim objShell
Dim main_database_file, main_output_file, main_sqlite_file
Dim TAB, LINE

' Set default values here if necessary
main_database_file = "G:\example\data\reporting\lastmonth"
main_sqlite_file = "G:\example\sqlite-shell.exe"
main_output_file="G:\example\scripts\display-time.csv"

Set objShell = createObject("Wscript.Shell")

sql = "select * from project;"

objShell.Run """"& main_sqlite_file &"""" & """"& main_database_file &""""
WScript.Sleep(500)
objShell.Sendkeys(".separator ,{ENTER}")
objShell.Sendkeys(".headers ON{ENTER}")
objShell.Sendkeys(".output '" & main_output_file &"'{ENTER}")
objShell.Sendkeys(sql & "{ENTER}")
WScript.Sleep(500)
objShell.Sendkeys(".quit{ENTER}")
Set objShell = Nothing
```

Comment: Please paste in some code.  How is vbscript entering commands into the sqlite command line exe (sqlite3.exe)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would agree with Jack that the doc states no difference.
However, why not pipe your commands in to the Command-Line-Processor? You can create a 'SQL' file containing each of the steps above and then execute the single run command:

Something like (not tested!)

SQL file:

```
.separator ,
.headers on
etc..
```

Then run this file as:

```
shell.run "sqlite-clp.exe mydb.db < sqlfile.sql"
```

There isn't any need for arbitrary timeouts, and you can probably pass in parameters too.

PS: It's probably sendkeys running in the context of a scheduled task that is the problem

Answer (score 1):

Well, according to [the documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/sqlite.html), the description of both `.quit` and `.exit` is "Exit this program", so I don't believe so, no.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only difference is `.quit` doesn't work on some Unix systems.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know that.  FWIW, `.quit` seems to work with SQLite version 3.7.7.1 on SUSE Enterprise.